# Timer on IoT Edge module

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-iot-edge

I have a requirement to run a task every n seconds to fetch some data using REST API on IoT Edge.

My first thought was to create a C# Azure IoT Edge module and have a timer on it to run the task.
Something similar to [SimulatedTemperatureSensor](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/master/edge-modules/SimulatedTemperatureSensor) project. But, instead of sending fake data every 5 seconds, I will do my API requests. I downloaded this project and started changing it. But it has many dependencies on other project and has a lot than what I need.

Is there a simpler project or tutorial that I can use?

Comment: You might consider writing this in Node JS. You could likely achieve it in about 100 lines of code and it has good support for REST interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iotedge-end2end-messageflow/blob/master/EdgeModules/modules/MessageForwarder/Program.cs#L192). That one sends out a message every few seconds but just the same way you can implement whatever logic you'd like.